# browserInApp issue with Google OAuth in quasar+feathers app

Tags: node.js, firebase, vue.js, firebase-authentication, quasar-framework

Scenario:
I’m building Spa end Android app with quasarjs.
The backend is a feathers-js server with the feathers-js-oauth plugin for authentication.

I am using an SQLite database to store users.

I set up Facebook and Google oauth2 login, and it works in Spa mode with simple hypertext link “/oauth/google” in quasar
https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/oauth2.html#client-usage

Usually, for OAuth Cordova, people use “browserinapp” plugin that opens a pop-up for oauth2 authentication to fetch the token.

The problem is that Google dropped support for browserInApp user agent as you can see here https://github.com/nraboy/ng-cordova-oauth/issues/283

Did anyone have the same issue? How to solve?

I see some people use firebase, but can I use it only for authentication? I would like to maintain my server app with user collection.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. Temporarily fix the problem in a non-optimal way

[image]

add a timeout of 2 seconds inside the signInWithRedirect () method and then get the result getRedirectResult ()

Only works in production mode

I opened a case at https://github.com/quasarframework/quasar-cli/issues/186